# Java: cannot find symbol using netbeans

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming and I'm using Netbeans as a compiler. I saw an open sourced and I'm curious to test it. however, I got an error and I can't run or debug it. I have a Player.java, MediaBar.java, and Main.java. in my Main.java, i got error saying "**cannot find symbol. symbol: class Player location: class Main**

**Main.java:**

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Main extends Application {

    Player player;
    FileChooser filechooser;
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        MenuItem open = new MenuItem("Open");
        Menu file = new Menu("file");
        MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();

        file.getItems().add(open);
        menu.getMenus().add(file);

        filechooser = new FileChooser();

        open.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            public void handle(ActionEvent e){

                player.player.pause();
                File file = filechooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);

                if(file != null){
                    try {
                        player = new Player(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
                        Scene scene = new Scene(player, 1200, 700, Color.BLACK);
                        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                        primaryStage.show();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        player = new Player("C:\\Users\\BEASON\\Downloads\mm1.mp4");
        player.setTop(menu);
        Scene scene = new Scene(player, 1200, 700,Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I checked my Player.java and it also has an error saying **"cannot find symbol symbol: class MediaBar location: class Player"**

**Player.java**

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

public class Player extends BorderPane{

    Media media;
    MediaPlayer player;
    MediaView view;
    Pane mpane;
    MediaBar bar;
    public Player(String file){
        media = new Media(file);
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        view = new MediaView(player);
        mpane = new Pane();

        mpane.getChildren().add(view);

        setCenter(mpane);


        bar = new MediaBar(player);
        setBottom(bar);
        setStyle("-fx-background-color:#bfc2c7");

        player.play();
    }
}
```

and my MediaBar.java code is shown below which has no error:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.Status;

public class MediaBar extends HBox{

    Slider time = new Slider();
    Slider vol = new Slider();

    Button playButton = new Button("||");

    Label volume = new Label("Volume");

    MediaPlayer player;

    public MediaBar(MediaPlayer play){

        player =play;

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setPadding(new Insets(5,10,5,10));

        vol.setPrefWidth(70);
        vol.setMinWidth(30);
        vol.setValue(100);

        HBox.setHgrow(time, Priority.ALWAYS);

        playButton.setPrefWidth(30);

        getChildren().add(playButton);
        getChildren().add(time);
        getChildren().add(volume);
        getChildren().add(vol);

        playButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                Status status = player.getStatus();

                if(status == Status.PLAYING){

                    if(player.getCurrentTime().greaterThanOrEqualTo(player.getTotalDuration())){

                        player.seek(player.getStartTime());
                        player.play();
                    }
                    else{

                        player.pause();
                        playButton.setText(">");
                    }
                }

                if(status ==Status.PAUSED || status ==Status.HALTED || status == Status.STOPPED){

                    player.play();
                    playButton.setText("||");
                }
            }

        });

        player.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener(){

            public void invalidated(Observable ov){
                updateValues();
            }
        });

        time.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener(){

            public void invalidated(Observable ov) {

                if(time.isPressed()){
                    player.seek(player.getMedia().getDuration().multiply(time.getValue()/100));
                }

            }

        });

        vol.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener(){

            public void invalidated(Observable ov) {

                if(vol.isPressed()){
                    player.setVolume(vol.getValue()/100);;
                }

            }

        });
    }

    protected void updateValues(){

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){

                time.setValue(player.getCurrentTime().toMillis()/player.getTotalDuration().toMillis()*100);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: is `MediaBar` compiled already ?

Comment: Check for your build path. Is Correct JDK added?

Comment: it is compiled sir but I have the class and attached it. i was able to edit the code and got that error.

Comment: I also used JDK 8 since that is the version required of the project that i found.

Comment: by the way that project is from github which is open source.

[link](https://github.com/hemansutanty/JMediaPlayer)

Comment: Those files should be found. You could try to restart Netbeans.

Comment: I am not seeing any import statement for Player.java and MediaBar.java in respective classes..Please check it..

Comment: Try to create a new package without the sample code and run it. The add your classes step by step. Classes in the same package do not have to be imported.

Comment: @Maia yes, right..